# Почему background перекрывает название кнопки?

Tags: css

Я хочу сделать эффект при наведении на кнопку, чтобы background плавно менялся слева на право, но он меняется и закрывает надпись на кнопке, как это исправить?

```
button:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 42px;
    background:red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 2s ease;
}

button:hover:before {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/cool-hover-effects-using-background-properties/

Comment: Может `button:before { z-index: -1; }`?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете вынести текст, который находится в кнопке, на уровень выше. Например так:

```
<button>
  <span>
    Text
  </span>
</button>
```

А в стилях прописать

```css
button span 
{ 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете добавить свойство `z-index` для `:before`, установив его значение меньше, чем у кнопки.

```
button {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
button:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 42px;
    background:red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 2s ease;
    z-index: -1;
}
```